# How to enforce Tomcat to accept DispatcherServlet url mapping, configured programmaticaly?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat9

I'm running a hello-world Spring WebMVC sample of 3 classes: WebApplicationInitializer, WebMvcConfigurer and simple controller with a single request handler method.

Inside WebApplicationInitializer 'onStartup(ctxt)' the DispatcherServlet instance is mapped to '/app/*' URL pattern and reflected in **ctxt.context.context.servletMapping** value as {*.jspx=jsp, /app/*=dispatcher, *.jsp=jsp, /=default} in runtime.

But for unknown reason GET e.g. 'http://localhost:8080/app/sht' is dispatched to Tomcat's DefaultServlet! In runtime the request's context servlet mapping(**request.request.applicationMapping.mappingData.context.servletMapping**) value states that onStartup() configuration is lost: {*.jspx=jsp, *.jsp=jsp, /=default}

Could you please assist in configuring Spring properly? Thanks!

Spring 5.2.2; Tomcat 9.0.30, running under Eclipse.

```
public class WebbAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException{

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.setServletContext(context);
        dispatcherContext.register(SpringWebConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = context.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/app/*");
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "cool.videoservice.controller" })
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

       bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
       bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
       bean.setSuffix(".jsp");

       return bean;
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class IndexController{

    @GetMapping("/sht")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        System.out.println("Oh, yeah!!!!!!");

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using an obsolete tutorial. Modern Spring uses Spring Boot, which (among many other useful things) handles all of this route wiring automatically. (Also note that JSP has a bunch of shortcomings; Thymeleaf is usually a better choice for new projects.)

Comment: Thank yous for assistance.
The point of using spring-web / -webmvc is to produce finally a *.war to deploy into an existent Tomcat instance. Would be great if result is as lightweight as possible(AFAIK, spring-boot has a built-in Tomcat).
JSP issue, as you said, definitely takes place. At this moment the key point is backend logics - if it can be managed with Spring, Seems, Thymeleaf is a good variant which can be utilized a little later.